# differences between liferay 6.1 service builder and liferay 6.0

Tags: web-services, liferay

I want to create web service in liferay 6.1. But if i do such things, like in liferay 6.0 i have errors like `java.io.IOException: Type {http://model.test.liferay.com}xxxx is referenced but not defined.`

Answer (score 1):

We have been having this error as well. I have posted multiple times on the liferay forums and contacted them directly (enterprise customer), but no one cares.

So we fixed it by staying on version 6.0.6

Answer (score 0):

I gave up after discovering these API changes.

```
in docroot/WEB-INF/src/META-INF/shard-data-source-spring.xml    
6.0.6:
com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.ShardAdvice
6.1:
com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardAdvice 

docroot/WEB-INF/src/META-INF/base-spring.xml    
6.0.6
com.liferay.portal.spring.annotation.BeanReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
6.1
com.liferay.portal.spring.bean.BeanReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
```

It seems not to be so easy to develop on 6.0.6 and to deploy on 6.1. (vice versa I didn't try)